# Passing Value from One form to another on click of datagrid View Row

Tags: c#, forms

I got 2 forms:

Ist form contain(Main form) : Datagridview, Save button and 'Search Employee' button.
2nd form contain : Datagridview and select button .

When i click button search employee button from main form. It open 2nd form and show details of all employees such as first_name, id, salary in dataGridView. When i select any row from that dataGridView and click the button 'Select' it pass the detail of that employee to main form datagridview.

If i repeat this process then it will opnen new main fram with that particular recod nd do not add selected record to previous datagridview.  so how i can implement this.

```
frmMain frmMain = new frmMain();
frmMain.Close();
frmMain frmmain = new frmMain(
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString());

this.Hide();
rmmain.Show();
```

Comment: You need to implement a model behind the form that contains the items you want to present in your form.  When you click you should populate the model with the item that you selected, and then redraw the second form, which should get its content from the model.  When you then open a new form at any point it should, again, present its content based on the model.

Comment: I am new to window application . So can when u say model. What is that , i have searched nd did not find it. can you send me link where i can study for model. Thanks for your reply!!!

Comment: No, sorry, the model would be any object residing in your software, storing the information to be presented.

Have a read about some design patterns:

Model View Presenter:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter

Model View Controller
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

You can declare public form on one page and when u navigate to another page then pass this variable this whole form like this.page then access this variable and all funcions